# If else condition in php

Tags: php

Hi i am using below `code` to display `city value` from `database`--

```
<?php
//echo "SELECT city FROM tbl_city_master WHERE id = ".$rs->city.""
$getCityQuery = mysql_query("SELECT city FROM tbl_city_master WHERE id = ".$rs->city."");
    $resultSetCityQuery = mysql_fetch_assoc($getCityQuery);
?>
<? echo '<strong>City-</strong>' ?><? echo $resultSetCityQuery['city'];?>
```

All is i need to Say No city Choosen in `if else` condition-- how can i implement that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will display city if avaialable

```
<?php
$getCityQuery = mysql_query("SELECT city FROM tbl_city_master WHERE id = ".$rs->city."");
if ($getCityQuery)
    $resultSetCityQuery = mysql_fetch_assoc($getCityQuery);

?>
<?php
if (resultSetCityQuery != null)
echo "<strong>City-</strong>$resultSetCityQuery['city']";
?>
```

Comment: Almost worked, but throwing an error `Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolen given`

Comment: My votes goes 6 down due to this question. what is the reason ?:(

Comment: @KritikaGupta, your question was so easy, you can find your answer by googling, I think most of people rated it negative because they think this question is not constructive or helpful for others and honestly I have to say, they are right.

Comment: right i will take care of that, next time. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using following code:

```
$results_count = mysql_num_rows($resultSetCityQuery);
if ($results_count > 0) {
   // do something
} else {
   echo 'No city Choosen';
}
```

or you can use mysql_fetch_assoc and check if false:

```
$results = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultSetCityQuery);
if ($results == false) {
  echo 'No city Choosen';
} else {
  // do somthing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (count ($resultSetCityQuery) === 0) echo "No city choosen"
      else echo $resultSetCityQuery['city'];
```

or

```
if (empty ($resultSetCityQuery)) echo "No city choosen"
      else echo $resultSetCityQuery['city'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are strongly advised to stop using mysql_* functions as they will be deprecated in upcoming php versions

You can check if the mysql result is set

```
if (count($resultSetCityQuery)>0) {
    echo $resultSetCityQuery['city'];
} else { 
    echo 'No city chosen';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach($resultSetCityQuery as $city){
    if(isset($city['city']) && !empty($city['city'])){
           echo "<strong>City-</strong> {$city['city']} ";
    }   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This following code

```
    if(!!$resultSetCityQuery) {
        echo $resultSetCityQuery['city'];
    } else {
        echo "no data found";
    or 
        echo mysql_error($getCityQuery);//if there is an error ragarding to your sql statement
    }
```